# Python with mysql query insertion - single parameter

Tags: python, mysql, insert

Below are the code that is not working

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib
import datetime
import mysql.connector

data['price'] = 100

# Write to database
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='pw', database='db')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

query = ("INSERT INTO records(price) VALUES(%s) ")
cursor.execute(query, (data['price']))

cnx.commit()

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

MySQL has the corresponding table and column.

- id (PRIMARY INT AUTO_INCREMENT)
- price (FLOAT)

There is no connection problem.

It gives the following error. Any idea?

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./sys-fetchdata.py", line
>   22, in 
>       cursor.execute(query, (data['price']))   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line
>   507, in execute
>       self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line
>   722, in cmd_query
>       result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line
>   640, in _handle_result
>       raise errors.get_exception(packet) mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1

Comment: @hiro_protagonist Thanks. You should put this in answer. This is where the problem roots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the [`MySQLCursor.execute()` method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) takes a `tuple` (or a `dict`) as second (`params`) argument.

in your case: it should be `(data['price'], )` (note the additional comma; without it the brackets have no effect) instead of `(data['price'])`.

Comment: Thanks, this is some strange bug. Takes me hours before posting this question.

Comment: i agree: the error message should be a lot more informative than it is...

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to find a solution:

1. Do not execute your query, instead `mogrify` and print it. For example:

   ```
   query = ("INSERT INTO records(price) VALUES(%s) ")
   query_to_be_executed = cursor.mogrify(query, (data['price']))
   print(query_to_be_executed)
   ```
2. Next try to execute your printed query manually in bash or phpMyAdmin and fix it.
3. Finally use fixed query in your python code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This should help the debugging process, but hiro had pointed out the exact root of problem.

Comment: [mogrify](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.mogrify) is specific to PostgreSQL database adapter `psycopg`. [MySQL Connector/Python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/) does not have `mogrify`, so it cannot be used for the context of this question.

Comment: Odysseas, I didn't know. I know this is wayaround but maybe author can use PostgreSQL database?